# Delphi IWinHTTPRequest SetRequestHeader

Tags: delphi, winhttp, winhttprequest

I am trying to send custom header values in a HTTP POST but the site I am posting to tells me they are just receiving nulls.

I have tried setting the values `OSName`, `OSVersion`, `ProductName`, `ProductVersion` as a `String`, `WideString` and `OLEVariant`, but no matter how I send the values, they arrive as a null.

This is how they are being set.  Yes I have verified that the values (`OSName`, etc) do have values.

```
HTTPOb := CoWinHttpRequest.Create; 
HTTPOb.SetTimeouts(RESOLVETIMEOUT,CONNECTTIMEOUT,SENDTIMEOUT,RECEIVETIMEOUT);

URL := sServer;
HTTPOb.Open(bStrMethod, URL, false);
HTTPOb.SetRequestHeader('MAXM_HOST_OS_NAME', OSName);
HTTPOb.SetRequestHeader('MAXM_HOST_OS_VER', OSVersion);
HTTPOb.SetRequestHeader('MAXM_HOST_APP_NAME', ProductName);
HTTPOb.SetRequestHeader('MAXM_HOST_APP_VER', ProductVersion);

HTTPOb.Send(xml);
```

Comment: did you verify with a packet sniffer like Wireshark, or a debugging proxy like Fiddler, that the values are actually being transmitted in the HTTP request? If they are, and they are still null on the receiving side, then the problem is on the receiving side, not yours.

Comment: Thank you Remy - I have in the past but was not successful.  Communication is thru a VPN and I have not been able to see the output

Comment: you can run Wireshark/Fiddler on the same machine as your client, even if the server is reached through a VPN.

Comment: Which Delphi Version are you  using ?

Comment: Using Delphi RIO 10.3